# SetFocus clears edit box

Tags: delphi

There is a problem with the chatter consisting out of a rich edit box and an edit. First one shows messages from both sides, second one is used to type in a new message. This behaviour changed from Windows XP to Windows 7 or between Delphi versions.

`vActiveControl.SetFocus;` clears the edit box. I don't want that. When the user is entering a new message and a message arrives from the other side it switches focus back and forth between rich edit messages and edit box which causes the newly typed message to be cleared. Focus must be set back to edit box after the rich edit chatter messages were updated. Is there a fix? It would be preferred if fixes work across Windows versions.

```
procedure TFormMain.ChatterMessageReceived( Sender : TObject );
var
    vActiveControl : TWinControl;
begin
    vActiveControl := Screen.ActiveControl;

//  RichEditChatterMessages.Lines.Add( ProtocolWrapper.Chatter.OtherNickname + ': ' + ProtocolWrapper.Chatter.OtherMessage );
    RichEditChatterMessages.Lines.Add( 'Remote: ' + ProtocolWrapper.Chatter.OtherMessage );

//  RichEditChatterMessages.Perform(EM_LineScroll, 0, RichEditChatterMessages.Lines.Count); // werkt niet goed
    if ColoredPageControl1.ActivePage = ColoredTabSheetChatter then
    begin
        RichEditChatterMessages.SetFocus; // must set focus first for perform scroll caret to work
    end;

    RichEditChatterMessages.Perform (em_scrollcaret,0,0);

    if vActiveControl <> nil then
    begin
        vActiveControl.SetFocus;
    end;

    ColoredTabSheetChatter.TabColor := clLime;
    FlashApplication;
end;
```

I came across this :

```
procedure ScrollToEnd(ARichEdit: TRichEdit);
var
isSelectionHidden: Boolean;
begin
  with ARichEdit do
begin
    SelStart := Perform(Messages.EM_LINEINDEX, Lines.Count, 0);//Set caret at end
    isSelectionHidden := HideSelection;
    try
      HideSelection := False;
    Perform(Messages.EM_SCROLLCARET, 0, 0);  // Scroll to caret
    finally
    HideSelection := isSelectionHidden;
    end;
end;
end;

procedure TFormMain.ChatterMessageReceived( Sender : TObject );
begin

//  RichEditChatterMessages.Lines.Add( ProtocolWrapper.Chatter.OtherNickname + ': ' + ProtocolWrapper.Chatter.OtherMessage );
    RichEditChatterMessages.Lines.Add( 'Remote: ' + ProtocolWrapper.Chatter.OtherMessage );

    ScrollToEnd(RichEditChatterMessages);

    ColoredTabSheetChatter.TabColor := clLime;
    FlashApplication;
end;
```

User might not be able to select text if other user is chatting. This seems to work in Delphi XE6:

```
Perform(Messages.EM_SCROLLCARET, 0, 0);  // Scroll to caret
```

[Documentation about this control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787873(v=vs.85).aspx). There are 4 versions. I am not sure which Delphi version uses which control version.

Comment: Why do you change focus at all? The RichEdit can be updated without giving it focus, and yo can scroll the text into view without changing focus as well. (For the record, I did not downvote your question; I'm just commenting to ask for clarification. I also removed the irrelevant "windows" and "api" tags, as your question relates to neither of those things. If you were making direct API calls yourself, the appropriate tag would have been "winapi" instead, but it doesn't apply here either.)

Comment: Yes, I'm quite aware of what a TRichEdit is and where it comes from (In Delphi, it's `ComCtrls.pas` that contains the wrapper). The question you've posted has nothing to do with that, however; it has to do with the VCL wrapper around it. "Windows" is a generic term for anything to do with that operating system, and "api" is a generic term about any Application Programming Interface, neither of which apply here (as I said). I'm not exactly new to either StackOverflow or Delphi. :-) You ignored the question I asked you, though. Can you read the first seven words of my previous comment again?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out in which unit this control is located. It does have to do with windows apis and such... anyway. I think this piece of code determines which version is being used, not sure though, I saw somebody else mention a direct delphi link to dll but I dont see it... so maybe it's some com control or so... not sure,   RichEditClassName = 'RICHEDIT20A';
{$ELSE}
  RichEditClassName = 'RICHEDIT20W'; From the looks of it XE6 seems to be using the 2.0 version. Apperently this api is used to specific which one to use, there is another stack overflow discussing this api: GetWindowClass

Comment: See this stack overflow topic about rich edit versions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294962/how-to-test-if-a-control-is-a-richedit-control

Comment: Certainly Delphi 2007 would use a different version than XE6, because the version that XE6 uses **didn't exist** when D2007 was released. But your question is about **the VCL wrapper** (TRichEdit), not about the `RichEdit` control available via the Windows API (winapi). I'm not going to discuss the tags any longer, though; I was making a suggestion so that you could get help more quickly by using the proper tags, not trying to start an argument or discussion. Good luck.

Comment: Older delphi versions use V1 of the richedit control and that version has many problems as you probably found out. If I were you, I would make my own wrapper instead of the VCL wrapper and force the loading of the V4.1 control as that one is shipped with XP SP1. If you want to support older dead OSes than you are better off with the v2 control.

Comment: Code in comctrls unit responsible for DLL version:   RichEditModuleName = 'RICHED20.DLL'; (Thanks for the tip whosrdaddy)

Comment: Yes I know, and your point is?

Comment: Cool story bro. However in the future, you need to narrow your question way down to a specific SSCCE (Simple, Self-Contained, Compilable Example) so that we can better assist you.

Comment: For info I tried without setting the focus to the richedit too - it sort of scrolled but the display was incorrect. Incidentally I don't understand why your question is being down-voted so harshly, a classic woods and trees case that is all.

Comment: - *"There is a problem with the chatter."* - Indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen such basic behaviour of a TEdit Change in many years...

In D2009 + Windows 7 64 and tested on XP. I made a simulation work without any trouble. I suspect you have AutoSelect set to True for the message editor. Therefore when focus switches back and forth the editor auto selects all the text and your next keystroke deletes it. Just happens so quickly you don't notice.

If that's not it you might have something else going on in FlashApplication.

Simulation using a timer:

```
...
edmessage.AutoSelect := False;
...

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  richedit1.SetFocus;
  richedit1.Lines.Add('Text message, interrupting typing');
  richedit1.SelStart := richedit1.GetTextLen;
  richedit1.SelLength := 0;
  richedit1.ScrollBy(0, richedit1.Lines.Count);
  richedit1.Refresh;
  edmessage.SelLength := 0;
  edmessage.SelStart := edmessage.GetTextLen;
  edmessage.SetFocus;
end;
```

Comment: Not new at all, I think it's always been there.